# Can i upgrade xcode to iOS5 without loosing my app operability

Tags: ios

I have developed an iOS application. My Xcode version is currently 4 and i want to upgrade to iOS 5. Can i do that without to be worry about the operability of my app later when i become on iOS 5?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, there's nothing to worry about.

Comment: Hi, is the iOS SDK version 5 the Beta one or final ?

Answer (score 0):

You should always build and test your application with the latest release and latest beta version of Xcode/iOS.

As of today this would be something like:

- Xcode 4.1 on Lion with iOS 4.3
- Xcode 4.2 beta on Lion with iOS 5.0 beta

You can install both of them on the same machine without any problems.

Also, I heard that starting with Xcode 4.2 you will be able to several versions of the simulator.

Comment: can you deploy an iOS 4 Deployment target application to an iOS 5 iPhone? and if i have two XCode, how do i install them so that i wont be having problems?

Comment: @Balcalso Check other SO questions about how to install multiple XCode versions. This is outside the scope of this question.

Comment: sorry for the trouble mate, anyway had answer my question already, thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to submit an app to the App Store you cannot build it with the Beta version of XCode.  Also note that the latest Beta is iOS 5 and XCode 4.2.

On the iOS Dev Center page after selecting iOS SDK Beta

> Xcode 4.2 Developer Preview cannot be used to submit apps to the iOS or Mac App Store. Continue to use the publicly released version of Xcode to compile and submit apps to the App Stores.